# Wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) for update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, debugging, minitest

I'm having an issue tracking down why my update method isn't getting the needed arguments. I have a similar test for show and the payloads are working. In this scenario the route in question is invoice/invoice_id/trip/id. If you can help me spot the error and give any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this type of problem in the future that'd be great.

This is the update method.

```
def update
  if @trip.update(@trip.trip_id, trip_params)
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: [@invoice, @trip].errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

With the following private methods.

```
private

  def set_trip
    @trip = Trip.where(:invoice_id => params[:invoice_id], :trip_id => params[:id] )
  end

  def trip_params
    params.require(:trip).permit(:trip_id, :depart_airport, :arrive_airport, :passenger_first_name, :passenger_last_name, :passenger_count, :departure_date, :merchant_id)
  end

  def load_invoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
  end

end
```

My failing test looks like this.

```
test "should update trip" do
  put :update, invoice_id: @invoice.invoice_id, id: @trip,
   trip: {arrive_airport: @trip.arrive_airport,
   depart_airport: @trip.depart_airport,
   departure_date: @trip.departure_date,
   passenger_count: @trip.passenger_count,
   passenger_first_name: @trip.passenger_first_name, 
   passenger_last_name: @trip.passenger_last_name}
 assert_response 204
end
```

Comment: Just to check, is the error 2 for 1 or 1 for 2 ? Are you doing any mocking / stubbing of the records loaded from the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling `set_trip` in `before_action` then `update()` method should look like this

```
def update
  if @trip.update(trip_params)
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: [@invoice, @trip].errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

`update()` is an instance method that can be called using object, you only need to pass `trip_params` into it, Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm a bit discombobulated. Why is it asking me for two arguments when I should be able to only pass it one. Is it an issue with my test?

Comment: Confusingly `@trip` isn't an instance of Trip - it's a relation and ActiveRecord::Relation.update does take 2 parameters.

Comment: @RSB Thanks for the clear example. I think getting the code looking as standard as possible will really help whomever has to maintain this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error message when the method is calling another which is being passed the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

update takes a hash as its one and only argument, but you are are passing two arguments (@trip.trip_id, trip_params) in the update method.  This is why you are getting the "Wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) for update method" error message.  as @RSB said, just pass in the trip_params and the Trip instance will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

RSB was right on the money. It turned out in this case that my issue was at the database level. The table didn't have a primary key so I was using 
`@trip = Trip.where` in the private method and this was causing it to come back with an array of possible rows rather than the specific one. I changed things at the database level to have a primary key and updated the private method. Voilà RSB's code worked!